# How can I append a description to a Zend_Form_Element?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, decorator, zend-form-element

I have the following Zend_Form_Element:

```
   $imginstructions = "Some description";

    $img = $this->createElement('select','img');
    $img->setAttrib('class', 'image-select');
    $imgdecorator = $img->getDecorator('Description');
    $imgdecorator->setOption('escape', false);

    $img->setLabel('Image:')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addMultiOptions($images)
        ->setValue('')
        ->setDescription($imginstructions)
        ->addErrorMessage('You must select an image');

    $img->size = 5;
    $this->addElement($img);
```

The description should appear next to the select box.
The problem is : When an error is thrown, the html rendered changes so the description shows up below the select box, instead of beside it.

HTML rendered before error is thrown:

```
 <dd id="img-element">
 <select size="5" class="image-select" id="img" name="img" style="display: none;">
   ...........options..............
 </select>
 <p class="description">Some Description</p></dd>
```

HTML rendered after error is thrown:

```
 <dd id="img-element">
 <select size="5" class="image-select" id="img" name="img" style="display: none;">
   ...........options..............
 </select>
 <ul class="errors"><li>You must select an image</li></ul>
 <p class="description">Some Description</p></dd>
```

Is there a way to force the error message to be appended as the last element in the DOM tree for the dd element?

Something like:

```
 <dd id="img-element">
 <select size="5" class="image-select" id="img" name="img" style="display: none;">
   ...........options..............
 </select>
 <p class="description">Some Description</p>
 <ul class="errors"><li>You must select an image</li></ul></dd>
```

so the 'ul' is at the end of the dd DOM tree.

Thanks, I appreciate your taking the time to respond to this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the css of the description class to 'position:absolute'.
That seems to have solved this.